# (Scaling argument) Show there is $v=\lambda ^\alpha u(k^\beta x)$ s.t. $\|v\|_{L^q(D)}=\|v\|_{W^{1,p}(D)}=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in \mathcal C^1_c(\mathbb R^n)$ and let $D$ it's support. show that there is a function $v\in \mathcal C^1_c(\mathbb R^n)$ of the form $v(x)=\lambda ^\alpha u(k^\beta x)$ s.t. $$\|v\|_{L^q}=\|v\|_{W^{1,p}}=1\ \ ?$$

**Attempt**

Let $$\int_D |v|^q=C,$$
I can set $K=\frac{1}{C^{\frac{1}{nq}}}D$ and thus get $$\int_D |u|^q=C\int_K u\left(C^\frac{1}{nq} y\right)dy,$$
and thus $v(y)=u(C^{\frac{1}{nq}}y)$ has norm $L^q$ of $1$. But how can it be adapted such that $\|v\|_{W^{1,p}(K)}=1$ ?

Comment: the question is a bit confusing. For example, $\lambda^\alpha$ seems to be a constant, why not just use a single symbol?
 Also i dont understand your calculations with the integral.

Comment: @supinf : yes it's a constant. My integral calculation is just a substitution.

Comment: @supinf: I edited my question. It should be more clear.

Comment: basically you have two degrees of freedom: can you choose $\lambda^\alpha$ and $k^\beta$ suitable?

Comment: @supinf: it's in fact my problem... how can I find them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch- Lets simplify notation, so $v= a u(bx)$ for constants $a,b>0$ to be determined. Compute the norms of $v$ in terms of $u$. You should see that
$$ ‖v‖_{L^p} = a b^{-n} ‖u‖_{L^p} $$
Also by chain rule
$$ ‖\partial_i v‖_{L^p} = ab^{-n+1}‖\partial_i u‖_{L^p}$$
Hence(this step depends on your definition of the norm, if you have a different one then the exact expression will be different), $$‖v‖_{W^{1,p}} = ab^{-n} ‖u‖_{L^p} + ab^{-n+1}‖∇ u‖_{L^p}$$

From here it should be easy to conclude that it can be done, and $a,b$ can be computed.